# Running a binary using find -exec linux command

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, find

odd question I am playing around with the Linux find command and can successfully find a script file, I then want to run it without spawning a new shell is that possible?

example:

```
$ find ~ iname script.sh -exec ls -s {} -exec bash {} +
```

this successfully runs the script but I don't want to spawn a new shell, is it possible to just run the script?

Comment: Have you _tried_ `-exec {} \;`? The `+` form won't work here for reasons that should be entirely obvious. That said, right now, your first `-exec` is still missing a terminator, so what you mean to be run by the second `-exec` is actually just an argument to the first one.

Comment: That's still going to spawn a new shell to run the script though. You can't run the script in the *current* shell since the current shell isn't executing at that point... `find` is.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the new process? What's the goal there? What is the necessity there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to source the scripts you find into your current shell? If so:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' scriptname; do
  printf '%s\n' "$scriptname" >&2
  source "$scriptname"
done < <(find ~ -iname script.sh -print0)
```

If you merely mean that you want to avoid more than one interpreter being involved when running them as subprocesses:

```
find ~ -iname script.sh -exec ls -sh '{}' ';' -exec '{}' ';'
```

...quoting `{}` isn't necessary for bash, but it's a habit to be in if one's code may be used from zsh.

Comment: I'm trying to find the script file and then execute it without spawning a new process. Sorry if this is vague I'm new to linux and doing an educational ctf, 
effectively I can return and run the file using -exec bash, but I think this spawns a new process to run the script

Comment: @TubbyTommy, "executing it without spawning a new process" is what sourcing it -- the first approach given in this answer -- does. Note that this means that if any script you source runs the command `exit`, no further scripts get run, because that `exit` exits your shell... but, well, you get what you're asking for.